# Why does using enum raising 'ArgumentError' in rails 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-7

I'm trying to define an enum as

> enum :bet_status, { 'waiting': 'waiting', 'running': 'running',
> 'completed': 'completed', 'disputed': 'disputed' }

but getting error

> `raise_conflict_error': You tried to define an enum named "bet_status"
> on the model "Bet", but this will generate a instance method
> "waiting?", which is already defined by another enum. (ArgumentError)

I tried with prefix option, but it still does not work

Comment: First of all, restart your app/console, sometimes these issues can be just from loading. Second, _do you_ have another enum? Can you show more of your model if so.